# How to use arrays as field in Rails model and convert it to string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

There is the following model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope { order(id: :desc) }

    validates :title, :content, :keywords, presence: true

    has_many :responses, dependent: :destroy

    scope :existing, ->{ where(deleted: false) }
    scope :enabled,  ->{ where(enabled: true) }
end
```

'keywords' is an array column in the database. But from my form I get not an array, just string(for example, "england football liverpool"). So, I want to do the following: when I need to use 'keywords' field in my form Rails will convert array to string with space as delimiter; when I need to save an object in the database Rails will convert some string to an array(['england', 'football', 'liverpool']). I can do it with a lot of code, but I hope Rails have better solution out of the box. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `serialize :teams, as: :array` and use `text_field 'post[teams][]'` in your forms to receive params like `params[:post][:teams]` containing an array like `['liverpool', 'what ever']`

Comment: Please, provide me with full code

Answer (score 0):

virtual attributes

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def teams= (*t)
    write_attribute(:teams, t.flatten.compact.uniq.join(' '))
  end

  def teams
    read_attribute(:teams).split /\s/
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it the best solution? May be serialization?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the best.. but it's what you asked for.  Delimiting with spaces is generally a bad idea, commas are better as spaces are commonly found in names.  Secondly, I would prefer to normalize the db for fast lookups.  Serializing to an array takes the db out of the index process

Comment: Yes, this looks like a regular serialization but made manually ... Also, "Denver Broncos" would be considered as 2 differents team following the provided code. In other words, just use serialization, do not try to do your own serialization system.

Comment: Guys, it was just a simple ... My system won't have any 'double' keywords, just simple as 'it', 'company', 'usa', etc.

Comment: MrYoshiji, can you provide me example with serialization? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I try to save string "A B" I will get empty array

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (no time to test this, tell me if you get an error):

```
# model
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  serlialize :teams, as: :array

# view pseudo-code
form_for @post do |f|
  # ...
  @post.teams.each do |team|
    f.text_field 'teams[]', value: team
  f.text_field 'teams[]' # for a new value
```

Then after submitting the form you will receive params like this:

```
params = { post: { teams: ['liverpool', 'what ever'] } }
```

And you will be able to simply call:

```
@post.update_attributes(post_params)
```

---

This code suggest using 1 text field for each `teams` value + 1 for the new value. Another way is to use only one text field and split on a specific separator (whitespace for example but `Denver Broncos` would be splitted in two teams) but this implies that you modify the `params[:post][:teams]` from string to array of strings.